# TyperError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, error-handling

Here's my class :

```
    class Person:

    def __new__(cls, first, last):
        print("Calling __new__() method of class {}".format(cls))
        return object.__new__(cls, first, last)

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        """Constructor of Person working instance
        (attribute initialization)"""
        print("Calling __init__()")
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = 23
        self.residency = "Lyon"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Person : {} {} aged {} years living in {}".format(self.first, self.last, self.age, self.residency)

person = Person("Doe", "John")
print(person)
```

and I'm getting the following error that I cannot seem to resolve:

```
Calling __new__() method of class <class '__main__.Person'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    person = Person("Doe", "John")
  File "test.py", line 6, in __new__
    return object.__new__(cls, first, last)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you and cheers!

Comment: You pass two unwanted parameters in `object.__new__(cls, first, last)`. Why do you redefine `__new__` at all?

Comment: I'm just trying to check the order of creation via `__new__()` and initialization via `__init__()` of the working instance of my class

Comment: so I only need to call `object()` on `cls` without passing the parameters?

Comment: Then remove the last two parameters: `object.__new__(cls)`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Cheers bud!

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so that I get to accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object` constructor takes no additional parameters. The right implementation of the `__new__` method should not pass the last two parameters:

```
def __new__(cls, first, last):
    print("Calling __new__() method of class {}".format(cls))
    return object.__new__(cls)
```